# Showing jQuery Modal on form data sucessfully submited to database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I am facing a problem with jquery modal Dialog box. I want the modal box to show only when my data is successful saved to database. I am using c# and asp.net, and on backend i am using Sql server 2008 R2. Currently my data is successfully entering and i am showing "the data is successfully saved on a label" after clicking on a button , but **i want to show a modal box only when i click the button and my data is saved .**

I have created this script

```
$("#Btndiag").click(function () { $("#myModal").modal(); });
```

and on content page body i have written this

```html
<asp:Button ID="Btndiag" runat="server" Text="show dialog" onclick="Btndiag_Click1" />
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h3>Settings</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Here settings can be configured...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have created this script <script type="text/javascript">



        $("#Btndiag").click(function () {

            $("#myModal").modal();

        });

Comment: and on content page body i have written this 
    <asp:Button ID="Btndiag" runat="server" Text="show dialog" 
        onclick="Btndiag_Click1" />

        <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Settings</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Here settings can be configured...</p>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
   </div>
  </div>

Comment: Someone please reply i want a solution for this asap ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you have to process the data in the back end, and then have the ASP.NET Framework execute a script for you.

To accomplish this, you use [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx) during full page postbacks, or [`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750.aspx) if the controls are inside of an [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx).

**C# code:**

```
protected void Btndiag_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // process database

    // verify results
    if (success)
    {
       ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, "Btndiag_Click1", "$('#myModal').modal();", true);
    }
}
```

Remember that if the button and the modal div are inside of an `UpdatePanel`, replace `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` with `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`.

---

Finally, just as a last informational note...your script (`$("#Btndiag").click(...)`) will not work because [ASP.NET changes element Ids when rendered as HTML](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs).

You'd have to work it in the following manner:

```
$("#<%= Btndiag.ClientID %>").click(function () { $("#myModal").modal(); });
```

Please note that you do **not** need to do anything with the button's click event. You want the framework to automatically run your scrip after the postback.